# ActionMailer doesn't work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

All of my app's functionality works except the email function. Everything works fine and as expected in development. I hosted the app using DigitalOcean's Ruby on Rails one-click server setup. Here is a link to the instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-ruby-on-rails-one-click-application-on-digitalocean

Here is my development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in    config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  #DEVISE WANTS THIS
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  #Action Mailer
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address:              'p3plcpnl0334.prod.phx3.secureserver.net',
      port:                 465,
      domain:               'finaltouchsecurity.com',
      user_name:            'receipts@finaltouchsecurity.com',
      password:             'xxxxxxxxxx',
      authentication:       'plain',
      #enable_starttls_auto: true 
      ssl: true }

end
```

Here is my production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in  config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

My Controller

```
def create
    @job = Job.find(session[:edit_job])
    @receipt = @job.receipts.create(params.require(:receipt).permit(:email, :information))  
    if @receipt.valid?
        begin
            email
            render :js => "window.location = '/jobs/#{session[:edit_job]}/edit'"
        rescue
            @receipt.destroy
            flash[:error] = "Error Sending Email!"
            render "layouts/fail"
        end
    else
        flash[:error] = "Error Creating Receipt!"
        render "layouts/fail"
    end
end

def email
            CustomerMailer.email_receipt(@receipt).deliver_now
            flash[:notice] = "Email Sent Successfully."     
end
```

I am unsure of how to check my server logs, but I am positive that the email function is throwing the error because the flash indicates so with my error messaging.

Comment: If you did not change the standard settings the you will find the log files for your app under `app_root_dir/log/production.log`. You can open a new shell and do something like `tail -f production.log` to follow the log file

Comment: It looks like you haven't configured SMTP in production. Try sending an email manually from a production console and you should get a useful error message.

Comment: Here is the error I am getting when I catch the exception error: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25 @Kristján

Comment: Here is the error I am getting when I catch the exception error: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25 @theDrifter

Answer (score 2):

`config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` is set in `development`, but not in `production`, so Rails is trying to connect to the default, which is `localhost:25`. You need to add that configuration to `config/environments/production.rb`.

If your settings are the same in both environments, you can move the config you have (both `smtp_settings` and `delivery_method`) from `config/environments/development.rb` to `config/application.rb` - the latter is global configuration that runs in all environments. If you do that, you'll want to set `delivery_method` back to `:test` in `config/environments/test.rb` so you don't accidentally send mail during testing.

Comment: Happy to help, @CannonMoyer. If this solved the problem, consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to help future searchers find it easily.